# Remote API, Objectify and the DevServer don't like transactions?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, remoteapi

I am using objectify 4 to write to the HRD datastore. Everything works fine in unit tests and running the application in devserver or production.

But when I try connect using the REMOTE API to the devserver datastore, an error is thrown when the code starts a XG transaction. While connecting with the Remote API, it seems to think that HRD is not enabled.
This is how I connect ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions().server("localhost", 8888).credentials("foo", "bar");
    //options = options.
    RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
    StoredUser storedUser = null;
    try {
        installer.install(options);
        ObjectifyInitializer.register();
        storedUser = new StoredUserDao().loadStoredUser(<KEY>);
        log.info("found user : " + storedUser.getEmail());

        // !!! ERROR !!!
        new SomeOtherDao().doSomeDataManipulationInTransaction();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ObjectifyFilter.complete();
        installer.uninstall();
    }
}
```

When new SomeOtherDao().doSomeDataManipulationInTransaction() starts a transactions on multiple entity groups I get the error thrown :

**transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed in High Replication applications**

How can I tell the remote api that this is a HRD environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 'unapplied job percentage' set to 0 and transactions using the remote api failed as if the devserver was running with Master/Slave and not HRD. Raising the 'unapplied job percentage' above zero fixed the problem.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem, although I only used a single Entity in the transaction. Raising the 'unapplied job percentage' solved it. Thanks!
Have you since come across a way to avoid the problem, while maintaining a percentage of 0?

Answer (score 0):

> If your application is using the **High Replication Datastore**, add an
>   explicit **s~** prefix (or **e~** prefix if your application is located in the
>   European Union) to the app id

For Java version, add this prefix in the *application* tag in the *appengine-web.xml* and then deploy the version where you have activated the remote_api servlet

Example

```
<application>myappid</application>
```

become

```
<application>s~myappid</application>
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Python_Setting_up_remote_api

Comment: That didn't work. I had unapplied job percentage set to 0 earlier, and raising this back above 0 made transactions on the dev server work again.